# Implement custom sharepoint workflow with aspx page instead of infopath

Tags: workflow, visual-studio, sharepoint-enterprise, state-machine

I am creating state machine workflow in visual studio 2010 and info path form (for approval etc.) is associated with the generated task. But i need to associate aspx form instead of infopath with the task as i'll have better custom code control and achieve required functionality.

Please refer any tutorial or video etc. which shows "how to associate aspx form with the generated task in custom state machine workflow".

Answer (score 2):

I think this can be good starting point:

[Workflow Task Forms (SharePoint Foundation)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms438856.aspx)

> You can specify custom forms for the tasks in your workflow. Because
>   tasks are SharePoint items that are assigned a content type, however,
>   the content type determines the custom forms used with the task type.

And here is one walkthrough that looks promising:

[Walkthrough: Creating a simple Sequential Workflow with a custom Task Form in SharePoint 2010 using Visual Studio 2010](http://ikarstein.wordpress.com/2011/03/30/walkthrough-creating-a-simple-sequential-workflow-with-a-custom-task-form-in-sharepoint-2010-using-visual-studio-2010-part-1-of-2/)

And some additional info here:
[SP2010 SPF WORKFLOW PART 4: ASPX TASK FORMS](http://henry-chong.com/2011/06/sp2010-spf-workflow-part-4-aspx-task-forms/)

Comment: I study the above links but now the problem is, we have to create different content types for different tasks forms. Is there any way of creating content type dynamically and assign to tasks different forms. I hope you understand the problem.

Comment: what's the problem with creating different content type?

Answer (score -1):

Do you want to use your application page for the task form? here is how I accomplished it:
[How do I customize a workflow task form?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/7759/how-do-i-customize-a-workflow-task-form/88784#88784)

Comment: This answer needs more detail to not be so dependent on the link. Please add more details and use the link only as reference. If the link breaks, the answer will be of no help to future readers.