# Create State Machine Workflow with Custom ASPX forms as Approval Forms/TaskEdit Forms

Tags: workflow, statemachine-workflow

I have gone through this link
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X_mPvr5nJuo that explains how to create a  state machine workflows for my document approvals in my SP 2013  site collection.

But I am stuck at, how to implement this using custom task edit forms using custom aspx forms [not InfoPath forms].

I know, this [THIS-LINK](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/34774/implement-custom-sharepoint-workflow-with-aspx-page-instead-of-infopath%20'%20THIS-LINK') exists as well  which discusses about the topic, but I have to create create a task that's associated with content type that's associated with **workflow.xml** file.so it becomes little bit complex.

**EDIT**

I have found out that below xml file can be added and add the nodes in the xml to associate the task forms:
 But due to some strange reason, my workflow is not getting in success state:

```
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
            <!-- Customize the text in square brackets. 
            Remove brackets when filling in, e.g.
            Name="[NAME]" ==> Name="MyWorkflow" -->
           <Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
           <ContentType ID="0x01080100D458D6BA4223471298243AA1C64A32F4"
           Name="DocApprovalContentType1" Group="DocApprovalWorkflow 
             Content Types"
           Description="Custom Content Type for Stage1Approver Form in 
             DocApprovalWorkflow in Subsite" Inherits="TRUE" Version="0">
         <FieldRefs></FieldRefs>
         <XmlDocuments>
            <XmlDocument 
       NamespaceURI="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3/
        contenttype/forms/url">
                   <FormUrls 
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3/
         contenttype/forms/url">
             <Edit>_layouts/DocApprovalStateMacWFProject1
         /Stage1ApprovalFormPage.aspx</Edit>
        <Display>_layouts/DocApprovalStateMacWFProject1
       /Stage1ApprovalFormPage.aspx</Display>
            </FormUrls>      </XmlDocument>    </XmlDocuments>
         </ContentType>
          <Workflow
 Name="DocApprovalStateMacWFProject1-VGDocApprovalWorkflow1"
         Description="My SharePoint Workflow"
          Id="a5abb16c-22e7-4207-87d8-c1fc12490c6c"
 CodeBesideClass="DocApprovalStateMacWFProject1.VGDocApprovalWorkflow1.
          VGDocApprovalWorkflow1"
       CodeBesideAssembly="$assemblyname$">
<Categories/>    <MetaData>
  <AssociationCategories>List</AssociationCategories>
   <!-- Tags to specify InfoPath forms for the workflow; delete tags for 
          forms that you do not have -->
           <!--<Association_FormURN>[URN FOR ASSOCIATION FORM]
             </Association_FormURN>
   <Instantiation_FormURN>[URN FOR INSTANTIATION FORM]
           </Instantiation_FormURN>
  <Task0_FormURN>[URN FOR TASK (type 0) FORM]</Task0_FormURN>
  <Task1_FormURN>[URN FOR TASK (type 1) FORM]</Task1_FormURN>-->
  <!-- Modification forms: create a unique guid for each modification 
       form -->
  <!--<Modification_[UNIQUE GUID]_FormURN>[URN FOR MODIFICATION FORM]                 
     </Modification_[UNIQUE GUID]_FormURN>
  <Modification_[UNIQUE GUID]_Name>[NAME OF MODIFICATION TO BE DISPLAYED 
      AS A LINK ON WORKFLOW STATUS PAGE</Modification_[UNIQUE GUID]_Name>
          -->
            <StatusPageUrl>_layouts/WrkStat.aspx</StatusPageUrl>
          </MetaData>
         </Workflow>
      </Elements>
```

Has anyone implemented this before? How to get the task edit forms in workflow after successful status "In Progress".