# Custom WrkTaskIP.aspx page

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow

How can I make changes to the task page's css (for example, change the title's dimension and hide `deleteItem`)?

*I cannot seem to find the `WrkTaskIP.aspx` page when I open my site (the site which contains the desired workflow) in **Sharepoint Designer 2013** (it does not appear in Site Pages).*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This page `WrkTaskIp.aspx` is located at LAYOUTS folder. But this is common for all approval workflow task form for the sites in that SharePoint farm.
You might have to make a copy of original page and customize the copy page.

For more accurate information please visit following link where detailed answer is provided to same type of question.
https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/8372/40602

Comment: Hello Yayati, I know that answer, I've read it several times today but it's not clear enough for me - "If you want to add an extra web part outside the form, then you will have to copy the WrkTaskIP.aspx page, and make your own custom one" - How can I copy the page? Where from? Do I have to have access to the machine that has Sharepoint installed?

Comment: It depends if you are having SharePoint on premises server then layouts folder will be at `C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS` of the server on which SharePoint 2013 Server is installed. The `WrkTaskIP.aspx` is an application page.